# capistrano-template: undefined method `template' for #<SSHKit::Backend::Printer

Tags: ruby, templates, capistrano, erb, sshkit

In order to use erb templates with capistrano (no rails) I followed the instructions given in https://github.com/faber-lotto/capistrano-template, but when running `[bundle exec] cap staging define_usermacros -n --trace` capistrano tells me that the `template` method was unknown to `SSHKit::Backend::Printer`:

```
** Invoke staging (first_time)  
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke define_usermacros (first_time)
** Execute define_usermacros
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as    deploy@10.33.66.12: undefined method `template' for #<SSHKit::Backend::Printer:0x007ff383bd4d80>
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
NoMethodError: undefined method `template' for #<SSHKit::Backend::Printer:0x007ff383bd4d80>
config/deploy.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.13.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => define_usermacros
```

I tried to up- and downgrade capistrano, airbrussh, sshkit in the bundle but to no avail, things remain broken.

At the moment cap doctor tells me I'm using the following versions:

Environment

```
Ruby     ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-darwin15]
Rubygems 2.6.10
Bundler  1.14.3
Command  /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/cap staging doctor
```

Gems

```
capistrano          3.7.2  (update available)
airbrussh           1.2.0
rake                12.0.0
sshkit              1.13.1
net-ssh             4.1.0
capistrano-template 0.0.8
```

And here's the capistrano stuff:

Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

group :development do
  gem "capistrano", "~> 3.7.0"
  gem "capistrano-template"
end
```

Capfile:

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
require 'capistrano/capistrano_plugin_template'
```

config/deploy.rb:

```
[...]
desc 'Upload user macros as rendered erb-template'
task :define_usermacros do
  on roles :all do
    template 'resource.cfg', "#{release_path}/resource_file",
         0o640,
         locals: {
           'user1' => 'blah'
         }
 end
end
```

... and there is of course an erb template in `config/deploy/templates/shared/resource.cfg.erb`.

Any hints on the solution or how to debug the issue welcome!

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the capistrano-template gem that you are using. I suggest reporting it here: https://github.com/faber-lotto/capistrano-template

Comment: This bug should be fixed in gem version 0.0.9

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/capistrano/sshkit/SSHKit/Backend/Printer is used for dry-runs (i.e. with -n), so the job works when run without -n.

The dry-run can fixed by adding

`SSHKit::Backend::Printer.send(:include, Capistrano::Template::Helpers::DSL)`

after

`require 'capistrano/capistrano_plugin_template'`

in the `Capfile`.